# How Long Will Swift 2.3 Apps Be Accepted on the App Store?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, app-store, swift3

I'm currently building a Swift 2.3 app that I plan to release on the App Store in Q2 2017.

I know Swift 3 is out now, and that technically-speaking it would be better for the project to switch to Swift 3.

But I have some very important librairies that I use in my app, an they will not be updated to Swift 3 until several months, at least.

So, as you understood I have a foot in each camp now.

What should I do ? And more importantly, **until when will Swift 2.3 apps be accepted on the App Store** ?

Will the **retro-compatibility of Swift 3 with Swift 2.3** Librairies be implemented anytime soon?

Thanks,

Comment: Along with picciano's answer, consider this... (1) If these third party libraries are written in Swift then they also will have the same deadline as you. (2) One can be more confident of the release date of Swift 4 then the retirement date of Swift 2.3. That said, I agree with picciano - if at all possible, go with Swift 3.x.

Comment: We can update to Swift 3 but it will be very costly in time (partly because we  would need to update/replace some slow-update librairies we use). And it would be preferable for us to update in one year when Swift 4 comes out with the stable ABI. Plus in one year we will know if the app is a success and is worth updating. I guess it all boils to the question "Will Swift 2.3 Apps Be Accepted on the App Store in 1 year ? In 2 years ?". That's an arbitrage to make

Comment: Well, since the definition of "arbitrage" doesn't include "opinion", I should probably bow out. BUT. You **are** asking something that **nobody** knows. I mean, worst case - the App Store doesn't exist in 1 or 2 years. The best case? Apple - who BTW, controls 100% of the App Store, opens up everything and allows devices to be broken too. Sorry if I'm sounding flippant but you are asking for opinions (which this really isn't the site for) and foretelling (which Apple spoke pretty clearly with Xcode 8.2 about).

Comment: The fact that anybody knows is already an answer in itself. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 8.2 (which is in beta currently) will be the last version of Xcode to support Swift 2.3. I would encourage you to transition to Swift 3 as soon as you can.

Application binary interface (ABI) stability will most probably be in Swift 4 to be released in the later part of 2017. This means that from that point forward, the binaries will be compatible. Swift 2.3 binaries will never be compatible with Swift 3, and Swift 3 binaries are very unlikely to be compatible with Swift 4. However, Swift 4 libraries should be compatible with later versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot you answer! In this case wouldn't it be better to wait for the Swift 4 release ? I guess  Updating to Swift 3 (core project + librairies) will take us days of work. It's an arbitrage to make, but once again it all depends on until when will Swift 2.3 apps be accepted on the App Store.

Comment: set `use legacy version` to `no`. Still you can use swift 2.3 lib in swift 3.0

Comment: It seem that you can't use some Swift 2.3 librairies in Swift 3 "test.swift:17:8: Module compiled with Swift 3.0 cannot be imported in Swift 2.3"

Comment: I repeat...Swift 2.3 libraries are not compatible with Swift 3.0 projects. It won't work. You will need to get the entire codebase converted.

Answer (score 0):

Now Apple Not Accept Your Project on the App Store.

Update your version of Xcode to the latest release of Xcode 9 available on the Mac App Store, which includes the iOS 11 SDK, and build your apps. Starting July 2018, all new iOS apps and updates submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 11 SDK. All new iOS apps and updates for iPhone, including universal apps, must support the Super Retina display of iPhone X.